# How to export jar file of a project that uses Gson jar

Tags: java, android, jar

I am creating a jar file that other developers can use to make their life easier. 
In my project, I am using the `Gson jar` file (gson-2.2.2.jar) for jason operations.

My problem is that I can't export a jar file that will work on its own.

Right now a developer that wants to use my jar file needs to put the Gson jar file in its "libs" folder as well as my jar file.

What should I do so that developers that wants to use my jar file will put only one jar file in their "libs" dir?

How can I include the `Gson jar` file in my jar?
Thanks!

Comment: Generally, it's a bad idea to include the the libs of other people in your library, as there might be some license-collisions. I'd stick to telling people they need to add GSon as well.

Comment: Since you tagged the question Android, I guess it's an Android library. In this case, you can change your code to use the [`org.json`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)-package, which is included with the Android Platform

Comment: Use a build system like maven or ivy?

Comment: Thanks, I will keep the Gson out of my jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable and even normal to require a developer to include some other jar in order to use your library. There's little to no reason to look into building it all into one jar file, and many, *many* reasons not to do that. Unless you have some very specific need to do it, just don't. It only makes life hard on the rest of us. The right way to solve this problem is to use some system that automatically manages dependencies like Ant+Ivy, Maven, or Gradle.

Comment: Thanks! Ill just do as you guys say and keep it out of my jar.